# Entering an only alphanumeric string runs into a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException but works like intended otherwise

Tags: java

I get an error when I try to type a password consisting only alphanumeric characters but loops the way I intended if I type symbols. This is my first time trying to make a program that writes and reads a file and I'm still stuck here. I tried to paste the entire code to a different class but still runs into the same situation. I have no clue what caused this error. The IDE I'm currently using is Eclipse.

**The full error is**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 0
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)   
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266) 
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359) 
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)    
 TaskPerf6.main(TaskPerf6.java:66)
```

**Source**:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaskPerf6 {
    
     public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String username) {
            return username != null && username.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        }
     
     public static boolean isAlphaNumeric1(String password) {
            return password != null && password.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Type L to log-in or R to register.");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();
        
        File file = new File("records.txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        
        //Register
        
        if (choice.compareToIgnoreCase("R") == 0) {         
            System.out.println("Registration:");
            while(true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Write your username (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
                    String username = scan.nextLine();
            
                    if (isAlphaNumeric(username)==true) break;
        
                    writer.write(username + "\n");                  
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("a");
                }   
                catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            while(true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Write your password (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
                    String password = scan.nextLine();
                    
                    if (isAlphaNumeric1(password)==true) break;
                    
                    writer.write(password + "\n");
                    writer.close();
                }
                catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("a");
                }   
                catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            
        String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to include the full error, else we can only guess. Consider what happens on this line if the file only has one line `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(1);`, yes, it will fail as out of bounds. Arrays are 0 based, so the first line is at `.get(0);` not `.get(1);`

Comment: I edited to include the full error now

Comment: This part of the error `TaskPerf6.main(TaskPerf6.java:66)` indicated that line 66 of your TaskPerf6 class is the cause of the error, which as we suspected is `String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(1);`. Now you need to do some debugging to work out if you need line 0, or why there is only one line in the array created by `readAllLines`

Comment: changing it to `String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(0);` still runs into the same exception except it's now `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` with the full error being the same, and I have idea what to do from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need two of the same methods; delete one of the `isAlphaNumeric` methods.

```java
public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String word) {
        return word != null && word.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
}
```

Your problem is here:

```java
String line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(1);
```

you are attempting to retrieve the second line of this file from the `.get(1)`, when you have not wrote anything to the file.

The reason why you are not writing to a file is because you are using **`break`** whenever the *username* and *password* matches your regex pattern.

```java
if (isAlphaNumeric(username)==true) break;

writer.write(username + "\n");                  
writer.close();
```

which will take you out of the `while` loop before you can write to the file.

You should practice breaking up your code for reusability. Very helpful: here is my solution for your task.

```java
public class TaskPerf6 {
    
    static String fileName = "records.txt";
    static File file = new File(fileName);
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    static final String REGISTER = "R";
    static final String LOGIN = "L";

    public static void main(String[] args){     
        
        System.out.println("Type L to log-in or R to register.");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();
        
        switch(choice.toUpperCase()) {
            case REGISTER:
                register();
                break;
            case LOGIN:
                login();
                break;
        }

        String line1 = getLineItem(0);
        System.out.println(line1);

    }

    private static void login() {
        // TODO
    }

    private static void register() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Write your username (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
            String username = scan.nextLine();
            if (processed(username)) 
                break;
        }
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Write your password (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
            String password = scan.nextLine();
            if (processed(password)) 
                break;
        }
    }
    
    private static boolean processed(String word) {
        boolean success = true;
        if (isAlphaNumeric(word)) {
            if (!writeToFile(word)) {
                System.out.println("Was unable to write to file");
                success = false;
            }        
        } else {
            System.out.println("Was not alphanumeric, try again");
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    private static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String word) {
        return word != null && word.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
    }
 
    private static boolean writeToFile(String word ) {
        boolean success = true;
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(word + "\n");                  
            writer.close();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException | IOException e) {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
    
    private static String getLineItem(int i) {
        String item = "";
        try {
            item = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).get(i);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first change to be done might be not closing writer in the first loop for username but in second loop for password.

```
            while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Write your username (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
                String username = scan.nextLine();

                if (isAlphaNumeric(username)==true){
                    System.out.println("username correct");
                    writer.write(username+"\n");
                    break;}

            } catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {System.out.println("a");}
              catch (java.io.IOException e) {System.out.println("");}
        }

            while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Write your password (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
                String password = scan.nextLine();

                if (isAlphaNumeric1(password)==true){
                    System.out.println("pass correct");
                    writer.write(password);
                    writer.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {System.out.println("a");}
            catch (java.io.IOException e) {System.out.println("");}
        }
```

Comment: I tried it and the username loop still works like I intended. 
It no longer runs into the same error after I changed both loops but it results in the password loop not breaking whenever I enter only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Are you sure you included "break" keyword at the end of the if block?

Comment: yes, it looks like this:

`while(true) {
    try {
     System.out.println("Write your password (Alphanumeric Characters Only):");
     String password = scan.nextLine();
     
     if (isAlphaNumeric1(password)==true) {
      writer.write(password + "\n");
      writer.close();
      break;
     }     
    }
    catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     System.out.println("a");
    } 
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
     System.out.println("");
    }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

When record.txt cannot be found and you try to get index 1 that's why you're getting the index out of bound exception. Please use the following if check:

```
String line1;
if(!Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).isEmpty())
   line1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("records.txt")).get(1);
```